# $stateProvider broke when I changed config to factory

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

If I use "config" instead of "factory", the dependency injection doesn't work in production (on heroku). So I changed it to factory and now the stateProvider doesn't work.

```
.factory('AboutService', AboutService);

AboutService.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

function AboutService($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('about', {
    url: '/about',
    template: '<about></about>'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`config` and `factory` aren't interchangeable and cannot be swapped blindly.

The proper way is

```
.config(AboutService);

AboutService.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

function AboutService($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('about', {
    url: '/about',
    template: '<about></about>'
  });
}
```

Just 1 argument for `config`, `AboutService` function. The code above is environment independent.

Comment: Thanks! This breaks when you add ng-strict-di and thus will break when minified in production. Been working all morning on the solution.

Comment: Error: [$injector:strictdi] config is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode

Comment: The code above *uses* explicit annotation and cannot cause this error. This is exactly why `AboutService.$inject = ['$stateProvider']` line is there. Wherever the problem is, it's not here, or your actual code differs from the that was suggested in the answer.

Comment: ng-strict-di breaks angular-ui-router for .config in Meteor 1.3 and now it's broken for Meteor 1.5 I believe. Fixed in Meteor 1.4

Comment: There's no sign in the question that the error refers to this line. It says about *some* config, that's all. And I don't think that this kind of break is even possible. Annotation is core Angular feature and it works the same for the entire API. You can try array annotation instead, `.config(['$stateProvider', AboutService])`, but it should work similarly.